# No option for showing for my 2nd operating system after restart

Tags: 17.04

I have dual booted lapy with ubuntu and windows,the problem is I am unable to start windows. Why this is happening??

Answer (score 0):

Problem lies in the boot loader .  It is not able to find your windows boot loader because of boot priority ..

just enter into the bios and check for boot options click on your hard disk boot loader if it shows the grub menu then it is ok .. otherwise you have to repair the boot loader from ubuntu ..refer below link

https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair&ved=2ahUKEwiRnZTM5fXYAhURTI8KHW0jAc8QFjAMegQIChAB&usg=AOvVaw3iJYUZ42a7jskQGCRBqbHB

Hope it could help you

Comment: Last problem is solved but now a new problem has started.Working in ubuntu is fine but when I want to switch to windows 10 a blank screen pops up and nothing happens after that. But if I write sudo update-grub before shutting down in ubuntu then I can open windows. Can you please resolve this problem??